# How to Optimize A Site For Yahoo Search?

Tags: seo, yahoo, ranking

**What are on-site on-page guidelines that can optimize a site for Yahoo search?**

Its been over 6 years since I have been running a number of websites and for some reason the traffic and ranking from Yahoo has always been disproportionally low. Given that Google sends so much traffic (*except for one site which dropped last week - the topic of another question*), I never found out what Yahoo likes (and other engines but lets leave this question Yahoo specific).

Lets exclude things like 'great content', 'good navigation', 'user-oriented text' etc which are a given basic for any site and search engine. I am already passed this ;) What I am looking for could have to do with page structure, linking structure, layout, length of various parts, etc.

Just a note, my sites are all indexed crawled by Yahoo already. Their SiteExplorer shows that they have index most pages (from 10s to 1000s for bigger-sites), just that they rank less well outside of Google.

Comment: Yahoo doesn't have it's own search engine technology anymore. Since 2009 they've been using Bing's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turns out I almost had the answer when I wrote the question.*

**Yahoo puts greater emphasis on in-page factors** such as headings than Google which puts more emphasis on anchor text of incoming links. Keywords in the URL seems to be much more important to Google.

Yahoo and Bing may share a common engine but do not return the same results. Yahoo includes more synonyms when searching for results, which gives more result having different keywords. So on Yahoo, a site may compete with sites that are ranked for apparently different keywords.

Answer (score 1):

As Renan says, they use Bing.  So your best option would probably be to start at:

http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/

However, look at how much of your traffic is coming from Google.  For me it's a good 99.9%.  So if you have huge value from one source, focusing energy on another might:

- Be a waste of time (your time/reward ratio will be bad as well probably)
- Cause harm to your main source

Also note a good SEO site isn't Google specific, they are fundamental rules that should help on all search engines worth their salt.  Google/Bing specific optimisations are probably going to be short lived and -EV (I've never seen any specific engine optimisations either, I'm sceptical if any exist past signing up on their local business directories etc).

Comment: +1 for saying that SEO is not search engine specific. In fact most SEO has nothing to do with search engines at all and more with how to build a site properly.

Comment: Since 92% of my search traffic used to come from Google but that went down to almost zero (I am working frantically on solving this)  reducing this dependency is a good idea. My expectation is to get traffic in proportion to the market share and Google's is not 92% yet! As I said in my question, I already now the general SEO practice but the disproportionate traffic indicates an uneven applicability.

Comment: @John - While it is not SE specific. Each SE uses different hints and therefore rank things differently. Knowing these hints would let me know what my sites do not rank in proportion to the market-share of search engines. Google traffic used to be (up to one week ago) 10X larger than any other search-engine traffic for at least one of my sites.

Comment: @Itai, most of the ranking factors used by search engines are going to be common across them. What will vary will be the weight attributed to them, their expertise in using them, and then there will be the unique things that they use that are either patented or not yet considered by the other engines.

Comment: You'll also find that since Google has the lionshare of the search market and (not coincidentally) the more advanced algorithm you're going to find that they are going to deliver the most traffic. Also, if you do some research you'll find that it is not common to rank well in Google and then also rank well in Yahoo/Bing. Yahoo/Bing just can't get their quality up to Google's yet and thus deliver different results.

Comment: So you are saying it is normal that the search engine with 70% of search market deliver more than 70% of traffic? How do they calculate market share then? A large percentage of people search but don't find then?

Comment: Yes that can be normal, don't read into it too much.  It's just statistics, although the global proportion of search traffic originates from Google, you might for example expect 100% of traffic to be provided to the website IReallyLoveGoogleSearch.com to originate from Google.  It really depends on a huge number on variables.  70% is global average, it's not a benchmark for your website.

Comment: @Itai: I'm wondering who studies search engines' market shares. Realistically speaking when I look at my server statistics I see all search engine traffic coming form Google and almost nothing from Yahoo/Bing, even if the sites show up still in good positions also in Yahoo/Bing. IMHO it's not worth wasting a buck/time optimizing ro doing anything for Yahoo/Bing anymore. The real life search engines' market share is 99.9% Google!

Comment: @Marco - That's what I was going until Google decapitated one of my sites. Several people, including one in Google forums pointed out this type of dependency on a single source is unhealthy for any business (at least there are still 60% traffic remaining from non-search engines).

Comment: @Itai, what caused Google to decapitate one of your sites?  Did you do anything blackhat, or was it just random.  Also, it is unhealthy yes, but good SEO should give you good rankings on all search engines.  Also, dependency on a single source doesn't necesserially mean search engines, he might of meant through other means such as social networking, physical sales etc.

Comment: @Tom - I am frantically trying to solve that mystery through a number of channels. It was sudden (lost 90% of Google traffic in 4 days) and unexpected (no tricks on my part). The way the results show strongly indicate a penalty (even long unique phrases do not return ANY results). Revenue fell 50% since non-Google traffic is completely unaffected.

Comment: @Tom - If they are the same why are the [non-sponsered] results different. Bing likes this particular site much more than Yahoo :) That's why I am skeptic about this being an accurate answer.

Comment: @Itai fair point, I've only heard they are the same in passing, and I looked at my weblog and I'm getting `Bing Crawler` and `Yahoo Crawler`.  So I'm not sure either.  I still strongly feel it's correct to say don't optimise for specific engines, but to optimise for SEO in generally with good quality white hat techniques.

Comment: @Tom - Yes. That's I started with but not what I was asking here. Despite, the good content, Yahoo underperforms compared to its market share, so I am looking for adjustments that affect how their ranking of my site (not how to make a site that only ranks on Yahoo).

Comment: @Itai I wouldn't worry about making your income from search engines balance with global averages as I said earlier, how do you know the genre of your site has only 5% of Yahoo traffic?  Going for 30% because the global average is 30% is incorrectly applying statistics.